# Javascript operator equivocation

Tags: javascript, node.js

Don't understand how I'm getting this wrong

```
var timestamp = snapshot.val().timestamp || 0
```

Gives me

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'timestamp' of null
```

Comment: that means snapshot.val() is null.

Comment: Use `console.log(snapshot)` or `console.log(snapshot.val())` to know if they're null

Answer (score 1):

```
const value = snapshot.val();
var timestamp = value ? value.timestamp : 0;
```

That way it should works, using a ternary.

it's the same as writting

```
if(snapshot.val() !==undefined && snapshot.val() !== null) return snapshot.val().timestamp;
else return 0
```

Comment: You could make it more succinct: `cont value = snapshot.val(); const timestamp = value.timestamp || 0;`

Comment: Nope, if value is undefined, value.timestamp will trigger an error.